# How to process a CSV file with different enclosures

Tags: php, csv, yii, fgets, fgetcsv

I am uploading a CSV file using fgetcsv() function . Now i encounter three cases as ==>

1) The CSV file is clean and contains no enclosures 
      --> ex : Name,Age,Address  ..in this scenario , the file is processed properly and uploaded

2) The CSV file has " as enclosure
      --> ex : "Name","Age","Address" .. in this scenario, the file is processed properly is i pass double quotes as delimiter in fgetcsv()

3)The CSV file has ' as enclosure
      --> ex : 'Name','Age','Address' ..

```
  in this scenario, the file is not processed at all and not uploaded.
```

I want to acheive all these cases ,means a CSV file that contains either of the enclosures then it should process preperly.

Comment: fgetcsv() is not a magic bullet. It is very flexible, providing you guide it, It is therefore up to you to tell it what enclosure and delimiter is used for each scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) of fgetcsv(). The function accepts some optional arguments. For example the *enclosure* (as the fourth param).

You need to use it like the following in your `3.)` case:

```
fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',', "'");
```

Comment: -->   thats right .... but my problem is .. if i am uploading 3 CSV files ... one is a simple CSV without any , second is a CSV with " as enclosures and third is a CSV file with ' enclosures ... then the code does not work for the enclosure which is not passed to fgetcsv() ... i want a way which can handle all these cases of CSV files

Comment: It is impossible to write code which automatically detects the delimiter or the enclosure of csv data. This information must be provided by the user if there is no convention for the format in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the first character of the File, If that equals to single quote ,provide 'fgetcsv' function single quote as enclosure character and vice verce